# Hyperledger fabric ca V1 . fabric-ca-client error

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

At command line i am executing :

```
fabric-ca-client register --id.name <> --id.type peer --id.affiliation peerorgs.1A --id.attrs <>
```

I am getting the error below:

> "Failed getting affiliation" .

But,  the affiliation  entry is present in the fabric-ca-server.db. Can some one help me understand why I'm getting this error?

Thanks,
Smitha

Comment: What version of fabric-ca are you using?  Can you also share the config file for the fabric-ca-server?

Comment: Thanks Gari Singh. It worked.

Comment: Glad to hear it

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using Docker and Docker Compose, then you should be able to do the following:

1) Use a docker-compose.yaml with the following contents (this is a slightly modified version of the one in the repo):

```
#
# Copyright IBM Corp. All Rights Reserved.
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
#
fabric-ca-server:
   image: hyperledger/fabric-ca
   container_name: fabric-ca-server
   ports:
     - "7054:7054"
   environment:
     - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
     - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_DEBUG=true
   volumes:
     - "./fabric-ca-server:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server"
   command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw'
```

2) The above mounts a volume where you can place your customized `fabric-ca-server-config.yaml` file.  Simply create a directory named `fabric-ca-server` in the **same** directory as the `docker-compose.yaml` and then copy your `fabric-ca-server-config.yaml` there.

3) Run `docker-compose up` and check the logs.  You should see that your affiliations have been created

Comment: this solution works. I wonder if there is a way to provide list of affiliations using fabric-ca-client node.js module or mentioning into env-variables into docker-compose file?

Comment: You might be able to add then via env variables in Docker Compose, but it's tricky.
In the fabric-ca v1.1 release we added the ability to add affiliations via an API after fabric-ca server has been started.  The alpha for 1.1 should be out by the end of January